# How can I clone an S3 bucket to a new account while preserving all ACLs?

Tags: amazon-s3

It appears to be impossible to clone an S3 bucket while preserving the object ACLs, which is making it difficult for me to move some data to a new account.

I know this is possible when using Google's gsutil cp command with the -p flag, but I don't know how to do this with AWS S3. Does anyone have any tips or ideas?

The closest I've come to a solution is with the s3explorer command line tool, but it does not have a recursive option. Cloudberry Explorer doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: [s3 sync merge request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/1535) - it looks like the code is there but not merged to the head. Maybe you could access it somehow. Otherwise I've never heard a way to do this. Also, nice XKCD reference :)

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can get that to work, even though it hasn't been merged into the official tool yet.

Comment: So, are you going to just move the data from account to another with the same ACL settings? Will just cross-bucket replication work for you?

Comment: Cross-region bucket replication only works for items added to the bucket after it's enabled, and not on pre-existing data. I ended up commissioning a mod to an existing tool to do what I wanted, and the commit is here: https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror/tree/d9528749dc1bb5f0b18f7c0fcdce6768d463bfd8